# How do I center an object with known width and one with unknown width next to each other horizontally?

Tags: css

I want to center an input form for an email address (of which I have a definite width) and a submit button (of which the width depends on language and font size) horizontally with about 10px space in between them.

However, nothing I've tried seems to work for that and I'm really desperate.

All help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: can you post up your sample code, give us some place to start from

Comment: Do you mean one on top of the other?  And have them be the same width?

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align: center` to a containing element.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/fvXGZ/

```
fieldset {
    text-align: center;
}

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input />
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways of doing this, but to get something that works in a reliably across multiple browsers may depend on the layout of the surrounding elements. However, something like this might work for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Center</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .outer {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .inner {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        #emailaddr {
            width:100px;
            margin-right:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <input id="emailaddr" name="emailaddr" type="text" />
            <button name="submit" value="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you simply need to make sure the container surrounding your form elements is itself centered or has "text-align: center" in order to center them inside itself.

For example, the following fits your description:

```
<div style="text-align:center;border:1px solid blue;">    
  <form>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" style="width: 180px; margin: 0 10px 0 5px;">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

That div will fill 100% width by default. However, if you want that container div itself to float centered, then use:

```
<div style="text-align:center;border:1px solid blue; margin: 0 auto;">
```

The "margin: 0 auto;" puts the left and right margins to auto, which will cause the div to float centered in the layout.